# Items of type 'subs' can't be consumed. response: -1010:Invalid consumption attempt

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, kotlin

I am trying in-app purchase in my app first time and i got this error. The payment done successfully and after successful message this error occurred.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Please check this code

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
                              data: Intent) {
    if (!mHelper!!.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}

fun buyClick(view: View) {

    mHelper!!.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken")
}


var mPurchaseFinishedListener: IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener = IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener { result, purchase ->

    Log.e(TAG, result.toString())
    if (result.isFailure) {
        // Handle error
        Log.e(TAG, "failed")
        return@OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
    } else if (purchase.sku == ITEM_SKU) {
        consumeItem()
        buyButton!!.isEnabled = false
    }
}

fun consumeItem() {
    mHelper!!.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener)
}

var mReceivedInventoryListener: IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener = IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener { result, inventory ->
    if (result.isFailure) {
        // Handle failure
        Log.e(TAG, "failure")
    } else {
        mHelper!!.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                mConsumeFinishedListener)
    }
}

var mConsumeFinishedListener: IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener = IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener { purchase, result ->
    Log.e(TAG, result.toString())
    if (result.isSuccess) {
        clickButton!!.isEnabled = true
        Log.e(TAG, "In-app Billing setup ")
    } else {
        // handle error
        Log.e(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message already make this clear? You cannot consume a subscription.

Comment: but after that when i am trying to buy that item again " Item Already owned" error occur.

Comment: Again the error message tells you the problem. You can not buy an item you already own. You may need to read the documentation. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html